# React increment likes to an API endpoint

Tags: reactjs, nestjs

Im trying to make a system of likes for each recipe that i have on my page. The endpoint works, i basically pass the id and when i submit, it increments the number of likes by one of that recipe.
Im trying to make the frontend part for it.
Basically im building a custom hook with

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const useLikes = (id) => {
  const [like, setLike] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async (id) => {
      const response = await axios.post(`
                https://obscure-river-28733.herokuapp.com/recipe/like/${id}
                `);
      setLike(response.data);
    })(like);
  });
  console.log("like" + like);

  return like;
};

export default useLikes;
```

Now this is the part im a bit stuck on what to do.
Im bulding the icon like this

```
import React from "react";
import { BsHeart } from "react-icons/bs";
import useLikes from "./useLikes";

const Likes = ({ id }) => {
  const likes = useLikes(id);

  return (
    <BsHeart
      likes={id}
      color="red"
      size={18}
      onClick={() => console.log(likes)}
    />
  );
};

export default Likes;
```

And on the app component inside my map i call it like this

```
                  <Likes likes={record.id} />
```

id comes undifined so its not making the post to nothing viable. Could anyone help me solve this please?

Answer (score 0):

Your Likes component should be defined like this:

```js
const Likes = ({ likes: id }) => {
```

or change the prop name when calling it

```js
<Likes id={record.id}/>
```

Api call is asynchronous so it should be done simply inside an asynchronous function

```js
const useLikes = async (id) => {
  
  const response = await axios.post(`
                https://obscure-river-28733.herokuapp.com/recipe/like/${id}
                `);
  return response.data;
};
```

Then in the Likes component you can use the useLikes function like this

```js
const [likes, setLikes] = useState(0);
useLikes(id).then((res) => setLikes(res));
```

Comment: I changed the component like you said but not working either way.

Comment: Does id still comes undefined ?

Comment: You should not make api requests like that as you have done in useLikes. It should be simple.

Comment: Just to be clear, my likes component will loose like this?
```
import React from "react";
import { BsHeart } from "react-icons/bs";
import useLikes from "./useLikes.js";

const Likes = ({ id }) => {
  const [likes, setLikes] = useState(0);
  useLikes(id).then((res) => setLikes(res));
  return (
    <BsHeart
      likes={id}
      color="red"
      size={18}
      onClick={() => console.log(likes)}
    />
  );
};

export default Likes;
```

Comment: if so, now i get 0

Comment: id is still undifined

Comment: try `console.log(response)` in `useLikes` and return accordingly the value you want